# Wordpress Media Library went blank after removing a plugin

Tags: wordpress

After removing a plugin call "Transparent Watermark" all my media library went blank, but files are available in server I can see it from FTP, how can I restore to visible in library.

Couldn't upload back because I have 4 years images :(

[image]

Comment: Are the files still there? What's in `/wp-content/uploads/`?

Comment: @PaulSchreiber Yes files still there in /wp-content/uploads/ with years and month sepereted

Answer (score 1):

**Hope this will help you.**

"Add From Server" is a quick plugin which allows you to import media & files into the WordPress uploads manager from the Webservers file

https://wordpress.org/plugins/add-from-server/

Comment: I tried using add from server plugin, its bring all the size images to the Media library (ex. Same images 3 shows in library its cropped different size) also i have to give one by one folder to add the images and also its not automatically adding to respective post.

Comment: The other sizes are thumbnails that WordPress generate itself at the time of image conversion.. used for admin panel purposes.. but this way u can have all the images imported in media library one folder after another.. some efforts need to make in order to recover.  Otherway is to check database and if table exist running query for the same

Comment: Hmm thanks for the support, As i know there is no any other way to do this :( and we cant remove duplicate photos know.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your database? They are stored in `wp_posts` with type `attachement` if I'm not mistaken. If you have a backup of your DB then you can restore it.

Also make sure to report this problem to the plugin author to prevent this problem on other websites.

**Edit:** If it so happen that you do not have a backup I would advise you to quickly add a plugin to backup your DB daily (or other external tool of your choice). The only option you have in that case is to read your uploads folder and re-insert everything in the DB. Here is a plugin to do that -> https://wordpress.org/plugins/add-from-server/

Comment: I had a DB  Backup and i tried that also, no luck. and unfortunately plugin last updated 2 years back and no more active :(